# 'dlltool' equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc

In Windows, an executable called `dlltool`, given with [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), is used to generate import library for a DLL file which is used for linking DLL files.

For example, `libmylibrary.a` for `mylibrary.dll`. But in Linux (i.e., [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) I haven't find any equivalent program like this. In `gcc` (both Windows and Linux), the `-l` options is used to link these import libraries.

So, is there such an application in Linux that can generate an import library for *shared object (.so files)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ld` (part of `binutils`, and invoked by `gcc` during the link phase) on Linux does not require import libraries; it is capable of reading .so files directly for the symbols required for linking.